# How do I use Laravel Pagination slider on an array

Tags: laravel, pagination

My view calls a JavaScript function to submit a post to a controller, which in turn generates an array and returns a pagination object based on the array. I used Paginator::make, which is working. But I want an "intelligent" range of pages on the returned object.

My JavaScript code is listed below:

```
$('form#form-retrieve-data').submit(function(){
    $.post(
        'mysite.com/retrieve', //route for the action page
        {
            "_token": $( this ).find( 'input[name=_token]' ).val(),
            'from-date': '2016-04-01',
            'to-date': '2016-04-15',
            'per-page': 20,
            'page-number': 1
        },
        function(data){
            var current_page = data.current_page;
            var retrieve_data = data.data;
            var start_page = data.from; //first page of the page range
            var last_page = data.last_page; //last page of the page range
            var per_page = data.per_page;

            $.each(retrieve_data, function(i, val){
                //handle each retrive data hare
            }

            for(var i = start_page; i <= last_page; i++){
                //create the page links here
            }
        },
        'json'
    );

    return false;
});
```

The controller of the action page returns the pagination object:

```
$from_date = Input::get('from-date');
$to_date = Input::get('to-date');
$currentPage = Input::get('page-number', 1) - 1;
$perPage = Input::get('per-page');

$retrieved_data = array(); //array that will hold elements to be returned back

//code to get retrieved data and push to array $retrieved_data

$pagedData = array_slice($retrieved_data, $currentPage * $perPage, $perPage); 
//$response = Paginator::make($pagedData, count($retrieved_data), $perPage); //this was ok but I want an "intelligent range of pages
$response = Paginator::slider($pagedData, count($retrieved_data), $perPage); //I was hoping that the returned first and last pages would be the "intelligent" range

return Response::json($response);
```

Is it possible to use Paginator::slider on arrays the same as Paginator::make?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to apply the filters on the data fetched from the database, sent using your ajax request?

Comment: Data is filtered from the database and depending on a condition, gets pushed to the array. I first used Paginator::make to manually create the pagination object. I just wonder if Paginator::slider can be used for arrays

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 4.2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655992/limit-amount-of-links-shown-with-laravel-pagination