# fit pagination on mobile devices (laravel bootstrap)

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

I can`t fit on mobile device the pagination. (laravel 6 and bootstrap 4)

I found this function for pagination ( onEachSide() )

```
 $products->onEachSide(1)->links()
```

The results are ok when the page loads (screenshot attached):

[image]

But the problem is when click on 3 and so on.... (screenshot attached):

[image]

How can I fit the pagination on a single row ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit amount of links shown with Laravel pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655992/limit-amount-of-links-shown-with-laravel-pagination)

Answer (score 1):

I know is not the best option but try to override the default Bootstrap 4 template adding "pagination-sm" class, this way on mobile it fits fine.